# Difference between the diff command 'diff -b' and 'git diff'

Tags: git, diff, patch, git-diff, git-apply

I have always used `diff -b` to make patches even when working on a `git repo`.

1. What is the difference between the two, does `git diff / git format-patch` also internally makes use of the linux/unix `diff` command? (I know the difference between `git diff/git format-patch`)
2. Also, how is patching with `patch -p1` different from `git apply`. Can i apply a patch generated by the `diff` command (`diff -b`) and apply using `git diff` ?
3. Is it a good practice to use `git diff/apply` when working with `git`? I have been using `diff/patch` and never faced any problem.

Please correct me if my knowledge of things mentioned above is not adequate.

Comment: cross site dupe https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/356652/is-git-diff-related-to-diff/598031#598031 also see my answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/598031/171025

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order:

1. Git has its own built-in diff but the outputs of both are quite similar, given the right options.  Using the built-in diff and the `git diff` front-end gets you a whole lot of automation, plus the output is always something `git apply` or `git am` will like.  In short, it's just a lot more *convenient*.
2. I've done this sort of thing (fed `git diff` output to `patch`, or plain `diff` output to `git apply`).  It works, although occasionally I have had to edit things here and there to get it to work, which is a pain.  It's much more *convenient* to just get a `git diff` if I want to `git apply` or `git am` a patch.  The biggest observable difference in general is that `git apply` does not do partial apply by default: you must add `--reject` to make it act like patch's default.  (Also, all those `.orig` files...)
3. Yes, because of said convenience.  When you go a bit further and use `git format-patch` and `git am`, you can mass-apply a whole series of patches, maintaining commit messages including authorship information and so on, and getting everything committed automatically.

Comment: Thanks torek! nicely put.

Comment: Incidentally, I've done the mix-n-match thing: instead of `git apply --reject`, just use `patch` to apply.  Sometimes the high powered electric screwdriver just seems like overkill, and I use the hand one. :-)